# Time format with angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have columns `time_from and time_to` in MySQL database. I am rendering the data with **angularJS**. The date filter works fine with **datetime datatype** but it does not change the format for **datatype time**.

```
appointment.time_slot.time_from | date:'shortTime'
```

Any solution to make it work with **time datatype**?

Comment: Angular will never interact with the MySQL database directly, so the format in the database wouldn't have any effect on angular; in angular, it will just be a string.  So the question is, what does the string that angular receives from your server look like?

Comment: it receives "04:00:00" from MySQL DB.

Comment: ok, well that's not a `date`;  a JavaScript `date` is the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00.  what you have is a `string` representing a time, which wouldn't work with the `date` filter.

Comment: thanks a lot. i handled it on the server side and changed the format over there.